# How do I toggle an object and make it permanently visible after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, visibility

I've made a site where the first page of my site is a youtube video, I want the navigationbar to be hidden until you hover over it. Once you go to another site I want the navigation bar to be visible at all times.
As for now the navigationbar dissapears when you hover over it on other pages of the site.

This is my code for the navigation bar:

**html:**

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <span class="toc-button" id="Block1-button">front page</span>
            <span class="toc-button" id="Block2-button">2nd page</span>
            <span class="toc-button" id="Block3-button">3rd page</span>
            <span class="toc-button" id="Block4-button">4th page</span>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.navbar {
background-color:rgba(213,213,213,0.7);
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Georgia';
font-size: 1em;
list-style-type: none;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar ul span:hover{
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.navbar.hidenav{
    opacity:0;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function() {
$('.navbar').addClass('hidenav');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll > 300) {
$(".navbar").removeClass("hidenav")
}else{
$('.navbar').hover(function() {
($('.navbar').toggleClass('hidenav'))
})  
}
});
```

I have an exmaple here: [www.skmo.nu/test](http://skmo.nu/test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this changes

```
   // hover to show navbar
    $('.navbar').hover(function() {
        if (!$(window).scrollTop()) {
            ($('.navbar').toggleClass('hidenav'))
        }
    });
    // show navbar after scrolling
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll) {
            $(".navbar").removeClass("hidenav")
        } else {
            $('.navbar').addClass('hidenav')
        }
    });
```